# XNA How to create randomly generated (differing) turn rates for duplicated objects?

Tags: c#, random, xna, rotation

I am making asteroids, and I need them to rotate at different rates and directions to give the effect I want. Instead of creating 10+ different things for each one, I tried to do the

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
   AsteroidPositions[i] = new Vector2(1 * random.Next(800), 1 * random.Next(600));
}
```

and that seems to work out nicely for randomly generated positions. I can have 25 randomly generated asteroids on screen in different places at once. What it doesn't work for is the rotation, because it is a `float` and not a `Vector2`. I have tried to do something like this:

```
AsteroidRotation = MathHelper.Lerp(-0.5f, +0.5f, (float)random.NextDouble());
```

but that gives me the error of all of the on screen rocks randomly facing a single direction. and the same one as well. I can not add `[i]` to it because it says that it can not convert `float` to `float[]`. I also have this for the `spriteBatch`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
     spriteBatch.Draw(AsteroidTexture,
                AsteroidPositions[i],
                AsteroidSourceLocation,
                Color.White,
                AsteroidRotation,
                AsteroidSourceOrigin,
                1.0f,
                SpriteEffects.None,
                AsteroidLocation.Y / 720.0f);
 }
```

so is there any way of me doing this? should I not be using the `[i]` method and use an `array`? if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Straight off the bat I would say using variables instead of a class to represent your asteroid is probably not a good idea. You mention in your title that what you have here is a duplicated object - this isn't even the case as you are not using any objects! Since, in your mind, you are visualising this asteroid as an object, you should be using a Class to contain it.

The reason why all of your asteroids face the same direction is because `AsteroidRotation = MathHelper.Lerp(-0.5f, +0.5f, (float)random.NextDouble());` is a single value, the same value you use for every asteroid's rotation.

Equally, you can not simply use `AsteroidRotation[i]` as this would mean that `AsteroidRotation` is a collection of rotations where you can to access the *i th* value in your collection by using `[i]`. It is not a collection, it's a single float value.

Two ways of solving this:

**1) Quick and easy. Not recommended. Not future proof. Will lead to bad habits.**

Make your rotation values an array.

```
float[] asteroidRotation = new float[25];

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    asteroidRotation[i] = MathHelper.ToRadians(random.Next(360)); 
    // ToRadians() important, XNA does not work in degrees.
}
```

And then in your drawing code you need to use:

```
 spriteBatch.Draw(AsteroidTexture,
            AsteroidPositions[i],
            AsteroidSourceLocation,
            Color.White,
            AsteroidRotation[i],
            AsteroidSourceOrigin,
            1.0f,
            SpriteEffects.None,
            AsteroidLocation.Y / 720.0f);
```

**2) Create an `Asteroid` class. Good practice. Uses object-oreintated nature of C# / .Net.**

Create an asteroid class which contains all the data and relevant methods for each. This combats your "instead of creating 10+ different things for each one".

A very quick class setup but it will get the job done:

```
public class Asteroid
{
    public Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public float Rotation { get; set; }

    public Rectangle SourceLocation { get; set; }
    public Vector2 SourceOrigin { get; set; }

    public Asteroid()
    {
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        sb.Draw(
            Texture,
            Position,
            SourceLocation,
            Color,
            Rotation,
            SourceOrigin,
            1.0f,
            SpriteEffects.None,
            0f);
    }
}
```

Create a list of asteroids and fill the list:

```
List<Asteroid> asteroids = new List<Asteroid>();
int numAsteroids = 25;

for (int i = 0; i < numAsteroids; i++)
{
    Asteroid asteroid = new Asteroid();

    asteroid.Texture = asteroidTexture;
    asteroid.Position = new Vector2(1 * random.Next(800), 1 * random.Next(600));
    asteroid.Color = Color.White;
    asteroid.Rotation = MathHelper.ToRadians(random.Next(360));
    asteroid.SourceLocation = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0); // Fill me in
    asteroid.SourceOrigin = new Vector2(0, 0); // Fill me in

    asteroids.Add(asteroid);
}
```

Make sure you do this only once, ideally in other your game's `LoadContent()` or `Initialize()` method!

Then to draw:

```
foreach (Asteroid asteroid in asteroids)
{
    asteroid.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

And that should be it. I don't think I've missed anything!

In the future this allows you to expand upon what asteroids can do extremely easily. You could create an `Update()` method that controls rotational speeds; have the asteroid move by giving them their own velocity.

Comment: Thank you very much for you input, i knew that I was doing something wrong, I just didn't know how to fix it. I will see if what you suggest works later.